# How to call execute method of swingworker at first and remaining code at last Here is my Code :-

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

How to call execute method of swingworker at first and remaining code at last .What i can do for it?

```
            imgHeight = getImageHeight(temp);

            imgWidth = getImageWidth(temp);    


            int Matrix = new int [imgHeight][imgWidth][3];

            MapGeneration.execute(); 


            //Matrix here

            Image lImage = Util.RGBMatrixToImage(imgHeight, imgWidth, Matrix);




protected int[][][] doInBackground() throws Exception
{      
    Matrix = createMap(imgHeight, imgWidth, imageMatrix, k);             

    return Matrix;        
}

   Can I use this returned Matrix on other page or to run execute() method at first
```

Comment: *"What i can do for it?"* You could clarify the question...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I mean How to run execute() method first n then remaining code

Comment: Write it in constructor and instantiate the class.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can i return a value from execute() method if yes then How ?

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Should I call execute method in constructor only ?

Comment: `doInBackground` in method MUST return a value.  You can get this value by calling `SwingWorker#get`, but this is a blocking method, meaning that until `doInBackground` exists, this method (`get`) won't return

Comment: yes you can if you want to execute it before everything else..but it would be helpful if you paste some piece of code you tried.@SOG

Comment: using SwingWorker#get method can i return a integer 3d matrix on other page from where the execute() method is being called.@MadProgrammer

Comment: Is there any other way to run execute method first then remaining code ? @SaurabhSharma

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know when the `SwingWorker` is done executing, you have a few basic choices.

The first is to override the `SwingWorker`'s `done` method, which is called after `doInBackground` exits, but is called within the context of the EDT

Or...

You could attach a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `SwingWorker` and monitor the `state` property, check to see if the value is `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE`

Or...

You could call `SwingWorker#get` which will wait until the `doInBackground` method exists and return you the value that the `doInBackground` returned or will throw the `Exception` that caused the `doInBackground` method to exit.

Take a look at [`javax.swing.SwingWoker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details